# Shortened syntax for writing template class method definitions

Tags: c++, templates, syntactic-sugar

Please look at example of the code below. The *problem* is verbosity of the template class methods definitions. Do I have always repeat `template <typename T, template< typename, typename = std::allocator< T > > typename Container>` before each method defined outside of class?
Is there some sane way to shorthand the syntax?

```
import <vector>; 

using std::begin;
using std::end;

template <typename T, template< typename, typename = std::allocator< T > > typename Container = std::vector >
class ContainerAdapter
{
public:
    void Push(T value);

    template< typename Iter >
    void Push(T value, Iter where);

    auto begin() { return _container.begin(); }

private:
    Container< T > _container;
};

template <typename T, template< typename, typename > typename Container>
void ContainerAdapter<T, Container>::Push(T value)
{
    _container.insert(end(_container), std::move(value));
}

template <typename T, template< typename, typename > typename Container >
template<typename Iter>
void ContainerAdapter<T, Container>::Push(T value, Iter where)
{
    _container.insert(where, std::move(value));
}

int main()
{
    ContainerAdapter< int, std::vector> ca;
    ca.Push(1);
    ca.Push(2, begin(ca));
}
```

**UPD** After comments, ty btw, I don't consider in-class definitions.
I'm looking for something like:

```
abc = template <typename T, template< typename, typename > typename Container>;

abc
void ContainerAdapter<T, Container>::Push(T value)
{
    _container.insert(end(_container), std::move(value));
}
```

Comment: Default should be omitted ->`template <typename T, template< typename, typename> typename Container>
void ContainerAdapter<T, Container>::Push(T value)`.

Comment: Define methods within the class to reduce verbosity.

Comment: You pay for what you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a macro:

```
#define TMP(RET) template <typename T, template< typename, typename > typename Container> RET ConatainerAdapter<T, Container>

TMP(void)::Push(T value)
{
    _container.insert(end(_container), std::move(value));
}
```

Your coworkers will hate you.

Comment: I asked for 'sane way', but thanks for laughs.

Comment: It's bad not only because of the ugliness of macros and issues they introduce, but cause it doesn't depend on actual template declaration. And when template will change it's declaration, macros will not change.